# Remove keyboard controls using cordova plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, keyboard, phonegap-plugins

I am using [cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard)  to remove keyboard left,right icon controls in iOS.

Its working perfectly as it specified in plugin

To hide the kepboard controls `Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(true);`

I added this code in my html page then it removed the keyboard controls but if I navigate to some other html page in that page forms also keyboard controls removed so I added this code to re enable the keyboard controls

```
Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
```

in that time it shows grey background instead keyboard controls please check the attachment below 
[image]

It would be really helpful if someone help to overcome this issue.

Thanks,
Ishak

Comment: What's the exact problem ?

Comment: He told us what the exact problem is already.

So, what does GapDebug say, if you run that command inside that console over there?

Comment: @Sithys console didn't show any error

Comment: @BipBip exact problem is I need keypad controls in some html page so that  I use this code Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);  but it didn't show keyboard Input accessory view controlls instead it show grey background